# How can I force the browser to present a file download dialog after retrieving CSV data using async POST call in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, post, savefiledialog

It must support IE,Firefox, Chrome and Safari current and previous 3 versions.
I have seen some solutions using download attribute which works in Chrome only.

The reason I am passing this data to server is so that I can add appropriate response headers which would force the browser to present a file dialog box.

The reason I am using a POST is because I need to pass a JSON array which should come back as CSV string.

I am using angular's $http.post service which is giving back the CSV string data but browser is not presenting a save dialog

```
Controller code

  var downloadUrl ='../csv';
  ExportService.postUrl(downloadUrl, 
            {customerID:$scope.customerID,
              startDate:$scope.startDate,
              endDate:$scope.endDate                  
             },
             $scope.selectedRows).then(function(data) {                 
                 return data;                            
            });

ExportService.js has following code.

 postUrl: function(url, params, data) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            params: params,
            data: data               
        }).
      success(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      }).error(function() {
        deferred.reject("Sorry, Could not fulfill the request at this time");
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
```

following function takes a csv string and opens a file save dialog in Chrome, Firefox and Internet explorer but not in Safari.

```
function(data){
      var charset = "utf-8";
        var blob = new Blob([data], {
          type: "text/csv;charset="+ charset + ";"
        });

        if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
          navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, "Report.csv");
        } 
        else {
          var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
          downloadLink.attr('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
          downloadLink.attr('download', "Report.csv");
          downloadLink.attr('target', '_blank');

          $document.find('body').append(downloadLink);
          $timeout(function () {
              downloadLink[0].click();
              downloadLink.remove();
          }, null);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to trigger a download in AngularJS.

```
function DownloadFile() {
     for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
         var iframe = $('<iframe style="visibility: collapse;"></iframe>');
         $('body').append(iframe);
         var content = iframe[0].contentDocument;
         var form = '<form action="' + arguments[i] + '" method="GET"></form>';
                    content.write(form);
                    $('form', content).submit();
                    setTimeout((function (iframe) {
                        return function () {
                            iframe.remove();
                        }
                    })(iframe), 60000);
                }
}
```

You can call this function with as many arguments as you'd like. Just supply one or more URLs, and this function will add a hidden iframe to your page, and keep it there for about sixty seconds. The user will never notice, besides the fact that he gets a download dialog message.

Comment: Thank you Steven for you trying to help. Please note that I have no issues when I use a normal ng-href and a server side GET request. It works and gives me desired behaviour. It is Asynch POST request where I have problems getting the browser to open a file save dialog.  Can your solution be modified to work with POST request with a JSON data body? If yes, please show me that code. Thank you.

Comment: To support a POST, simply change the GET attribute in my code to POST, and that should work. In regards to the JSON data body: isn't the file generated on the server and streamed to the browser? Or is the data that should be in the file being saved? My solution will only work if the file is created to the browser and streamed.